# Getting data from JSON for further use

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, graph, alpha-vantage

I am very new to this. But what I am trying to achieve eventually is the plotting of a real time graph of stock data onto a webpage.

I have the following code that takes the data from the Alpha Vantage API and returns in JSON.

```
var apiKey = "<key>";
var symbol = "MSFT";
var interval = "1min";

var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol="+symbol+"&interval="+interval+"&apikey="+apiKey;

$(function() {
    var $stocks = $('#stocks');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,

        success: function(stockInfo) {
            console.log('success', stockInfo);
        }

    });
});
```

When I run the code, the following is printed to the console.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-10-04 16:00:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2017-10-04 16:00:00": {
        "1. open": "74.6850",
        "2. high": "74.7200",
        "3. low": "74.6500",
        "4. close": "74.6900",
        "5. volume": "1664269"
    },
    "2017-10-04 15:59:00": {
        "1. open": "74.6800",
        "2. high": "74.7000",
        "3. low": "74.6800",
        "4. close": "74.6850",
        "5. volume": "201999"
    },
```

etc. etc. printing all the stock prices,
An example is here:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo
```

So basically, I can see there are multiple objects here? There is the meta data followed by the stock price data. I am not sure how I access this information.

I want to be able to store the open, high, low and close price such that I can plot a candle graph with the data later. I am not sure how I can retrieve that data and save it somewhere.

Following that, I want to plot the graph in real time, so how would I keep making api calls so that I can keep getting the updated information?

Comment: Don't ever post your access keys in a question. I edited out your api key, although anyone with enough rep can still see it (I suggest regenerating it).

Answer (score -1):

My reccomendation will be to input this into the console, as you have done already, and then open it in your web broswer with the inspector (Ctrl + shift + i in chrome). What this should do is allow you to see the object and all of it's components, so you can see the structure. Similarly, you can use

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

in order to see all the keys, so looping for each key may tell you what is where and from there, you can sufficiently code.